# Anti-Aliasing turned off in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, cs6, mac, anti-aliasing

I was trying to make my own custom shapes in Photoshop, so I first started out with an ellipse. I saw that all the shapes had pixelated edges. I went to turn Anti-Aliasing on in the marquee tool but it was grayed out. I couldn't select it.

I didn't touch Photoshop for a while, but now after 1 or 2 months this happened. Can someone please tell me how to turn it back on again? I'm on a MacBook Pro 10.8.4 and I'm using Photoshop CS6.

Comment: I don't have cs6, but from what I've been told, one of its features is that you can now turn anti aliasing off in photoshop for shape layers. This is probably the one feature I know of that makes me want it, as yes, you're out of luck with shapes in ps here, and it makes creating web UI elements a pain sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Anti-Aliasing in the marquee tool is not going to help you, unless you are using the elliptical marquee tool to "Fill" an elliptical selection (the rectangular marquee won't give you the option to anti-alis).

The Ellipse Tool draws the shape in a vector format. It sounds like your document resolution is low and/or you are zoomed in on your canvas. Use <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to verify that your resolution is adequate.